# What Google Sheet function can i use to Calculate Cash on Hand?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet which is like a register where I keep all purchases for a business. I have purchases made with different types of methods. I would like to specifically be able to track the amount of cash on hand at all times. I have a sheet I have created that already calculates other stuff by formulas. Here is a Public link to a demo version: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mArgTCpxYajmk2bOkE3aIaDTevajYxvsQW5P2cJbb8k/edit?usp=sharing

What I need exactly is a formula that will subtract cash purchases from the on hand balance calculated by adding the Replenishment column then subtracting from the Costs field but only if its a cash purchased item.

```
=IF(D4:D="Cash"),=Sum(L4:L) - Sum(F4:F)
```

Cash on hand to reflect actual amount and deduct cost amount of cash purchases.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is probably to create a new column containing conditional values and then sum the new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why anyone would want the result escapes me but, where the row contains `Cash` in ColumnD:

```
=sumif(D:D,"Cash",L:L)-sumif(D:D,"Cash",F:F)
```

will add the ColumnL values and subtract the ColumnF ones.

```
=sum(L:L)-sumif(D:D,"Cash",F:F)
```

would seem to make a little more sense.